# angularJS - connect multiple droplist and comboboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, combobox

I have a form with 2 dropdown-lists and 1 combobox.
Dropdown-list 1 has the 'groups', the second one contains the elements

The combobox contains a collection of data of combined groups and elements.

Example:

```
<select ng-model="currentCombo" ng-model="currentItem.group"  
    ng-options="item.label for item in data.subdata.groups"></select>
<select ng-model="currentCombo" ng-model="currentItem.Elements"  
    ng-options="item.label for item in data.subdata.elements"></select>

<button ng-click="updateCombination()">Update combination</button>

<select multiple ng-model="selectedItem" 
    ng-options="(item.group.label + ' : ' + item.elements.label) for item in data.combinations"></select>
```

Now, when I click the button, I add the new combination or, if it exists already, change the current one.

**What I'm trying to achieve now is that, when you select an element in the combobox, it autoselects those 2 elements in the 2 separate dropdownlists.**

Keep in mind that not all combinations exists: it is possible that a group has no elements yet.

In JS I run this code to add/update a combination:

```
$scope.updateCombination = function()
{
    var isUpdate = false;
    for (item in $scope.data['combinations'])
    {
        if ($scope.data['combinations'][item]['group']['id'] == $scope.currentCombo.group['id'])
        {
            $scope.data['combinations'][item]['element'] =  $scope.currentCombo['element'];
            isUpdate = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isUpdate)
    $scope.data['combinations'].push($scope.currentCombo);

    $scope.currentCombo = "";

}
```